# How to use cv2.ellipse in Google Colab?

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I'm trying to conduct object tracking and I've been read that ellipse boundary box is better than the usual rectangular box. So I tried to make one.

here is the code that I use:

```
cv2.ellipse(frame, [np.int0(location).reshape((-1, 1, 2))], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

and here is the outcome of that code

```
an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

the full code for making the bounding box

```
state = siamese_track(state, frame, mask_enable=True, refine_enable=True, device=device)
  location = state['ploygon'].flatten()
  mask = state['mask'] > state['p'].seg_thr

  frame[:, :, 2] = (mask > 0) * 255 + (mask == 0) * frame[:, :, 2]
  cv2.ellipse(frame, [np.int0(location).reshape((-1, 1, 2))], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

it works fine if I use cv2.polyline, do I need to input the mathematical formula first or is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation for cv2.ellipse](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse). It doesn't look like this function takes booleans anywhere in the arguments. Try specifying the inputs to the function explicitly, like cv2.ellipse(img = frame, ...).

That error message is telling you that somewhere in the function call, you are giving it a tuple where it expects an integer in the order of arguments. This must be either the second or fourth arguments.

Comment: I still confused how should I get the center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle because what I want it the ellipse will move and reshape itself when the object moving and I also added the full code.

Comment: cv.EllipseBox(img, box, color) takes an image, RotatedRect and color. All you would need to do is find a bounding RotatedRect of the object moving

Comment: it didn't work, I don't know why but cv.EllipseBox cannot be use in Colab. so instead I've been thinking to use mathematical formula 20*cos(radians(frame)) and 10*sin(radians(frame). but I can't figure it out. how can I put the location.